# Action Script 3. Timer MM:SS doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, time, timer

I'm creating app and I need to show game time MM:SS format. But I don't know why timer doesn't wrok It shows 0:00.359 (359 of miliseconds) and not change. Where is the problem? I can't find It. Thank you.

```
    var timer:Timer; //import flash.utils.Timer;
    var txtTime:TextField;
    var tmpTime:Number;  //this will store the time when the game is started    

//your constructor:
public function MemoryGame()
{
    timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick

    txtTime = new TextField();
    addChild(txtTime);

    tmpTime = flash.utils.getTimer();
    timer.start(); //start the timer
    //....the rest of your code
}

private function tick(e:Event):void {
    txtTime.text = showTimePassed(flash.utils.getTimer() - tmpTime);
}

//this function will format your time like a stopwatch
function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {
  var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
  var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds

  var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
  var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 


  if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
    leadingZeroMS = "0";
  }

  var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

  if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
    leadingZeroS = "0";
  }

  var minutes = Math.floor( (time / (60 * 1000) ) ); //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
  return minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds + "." + leadingZeroMS + miliseconds;
}


//in your you-win block of code:
var score = flash.utils.getTimer() - tmpTime; //this store how many milliseconds it took them to complete the game.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 timer.currentCount
```

instead of

```
 flash.utils.getTimer()
```

It will return the number of times the timer has fired the TIMER-Event.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on timer.currentCount. Timers don't hit at exact time. In fact, in any timer implementations, all they can guarantee is that it won't hit before a certain time. In other words, you tick() function would never hit before 1 second, but can quite often take 1.035 (randomly added extra duration) seconds

Answer (score 0):

You need not do this.

```
var time = getTimer() - startTime;
```

In your code, startTime is already time elapsed due to

```
showTimePassed(flash.utils.getTimer() - tmpTime);
```

OR
you can call

```
showTimePassed();
```

and change time calculation as

```
var time = getTimer() - tmpTime;
```